# refusal of UK visa for dishonesty

Tags: visas, uk

I am Maria Titova, work at Mariinsky in St.Petersburg. I have criminal record in UK. I can to get visitor visa renewed ?

Comment: There is no way we can know the answer to this. It depends on a lot of things, including what the crime was, how long ago, and what your other circumstances are. If you are prepared to share those details please edit them into the question, but even then we can't say for sure. Only by applying can you find out for sure.

Comment: Is your criminal record for "dishonesty" or were you refused a visa for being dishonest about your criminal record?

Answer (score 2):

The application form will ask your criminal history. If you lie about it, your application will be refused. If you tell the truth, your application may be refused or it may be approved, your chances depend on what it was and when.

If going to the UK is important for you, consider hiring an immigration lawyer in the UK, but this will be expensive and it might not help.